# use ALTER TABLE to add foreign key

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use ALTER TABLE to create a foreign key in MYSQL. I have already created and checked the primary key. This is what I have done so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CUSTOMER;
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUS_CODE int, 
CUS_LNAME varchar(15),
CUS_FNAME varchar(15),
CUS_INITIAL varchar(1),
CUS_AREACODE varchar(3),
CUS_PHONE varchar(8),
CUS_BALANCE float(8)

);
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_cust_code primary key(CUS_CODE);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cus_lname FOREIGN KEY(CUS_LNAME)REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUS_LNAME);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10010','Ramas','Alfred','A','615','844-2573','0');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10011','Dunne','Leona','K','713','894-1238','0');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10012','Smith','Kathy','W','615','894-2285','345.86');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10013','Olowski','Paul','F','615','894-2180','536.75');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10014','Orlando','Myron','','615','222-1672','0');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10015','O''Brian','Amy','B','713','442-3381','0');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10016','Brown','James','G','615','297-1228','221.19');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10017','Williams','George','','615','290-2556','768.93');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10018','Farriss','Anne','G','713','382-7185','216.55');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('10019','Smith','Olette','K','615','297-3809','0');
```

Comment: It doesn't make good sense for a foreign key in a table to point to the same column in the same table.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: use ALTER TABLE to make one of the varchar's a foreign key.

Comment: OK, to which table does the `CUS_LNAME` point?

Comment: the CUSTOMER table

Comment: This is not making sense to me

Comment: my teacher wants me to use ALTER table to make one of them a foreign key. I was trying to make CUS_LNAME a foreign key

Comment: @AubriannaMakaylaBrown I'm sorry but, do you know why foreign key is used? It is used  to link `two` tables together.

Comment: please read about it here  and understand [SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);

this is the format of alter query in mysql

Answer (score 0):

This would work for me:

```
ALTER TABLE State ADD FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES Country(id);
```